# Access properties in another class without allocating that class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, allocation

Currently I want to improve the structure of my app and what I am trying to do is access the properties that I made in my first CCLayer (Cocos2D) class in another class. Now obviously I could just allocate it and then I can access it but then the init method gets called and things just go downhill from there.

Anyway, is there ANY way where I can access the property in my other CCLayer class without allocating it again?

Also, I already have a Singleton in my app but I have so many variables in it and it has gotten so messy. Is there ANY other way besides using a Singleton?

I already have the properties set up its just that I need to access it in another class without an allocating technique.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered creating a singleton class with a reference to the first CCLayer and using that to access the property in the second CCLayer?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "things just go downhill"? If you need to access properties of a class, you need to have an instance of that class. You either need to create a new one or get a reference to the one you've already created. Posting some code would help us help you.

Comment: Meaning that everything in my init method could get allocated twice, that is why I want to figure this out.

Comment: @WendiKidd I am doing that now! But whenever I do something like gameLayer.myBool (where myBool is the property), it never finds that BOOL! And comes up with a warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Singleton class. I normally do it that way:

**Header**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Configuration : NSObject {
    NSString *serverPath;
    NSString *configurationServicePath;
}

// Single instance
+ (Configuration *) configuration;
```

**Implementation**:

```
@implementation Configuration
@synthesize serverPath, configurationServicePath;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
      // init
    }

    return self;
}


+ (Configuration *) configuration
{
    static Configuration *configuration;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!configuration) {
            configuration = [[Configuration alloc] init];
        }   

        return configuration;
    }
}
```

So everytime your using your class, you can just get the instance (if there is already one, if not it creates the instances just once) with the following line:

```
Configuration configuration = [Configuration configuration];
```

Comment: I do have a Singleton in my app but there are just so many variables and things there and it gets messy. Theres no other way?

Comment: But then you should change your questions and form it like if there is no other option than a singleton class.

Comment: @iBradApps I'd say this is the best way.  The purpose of the singleton (in this case) is to hold variables that a lot of classes need access to.  I'm sure they're *are* other ways, but this works :)

Comment: @iBradApps You could have more than one singleton, too, if you wanted, to keep things neater--break them up by what they're used for (and what classes need visibility of them).  There's no reason you're constrained to just have one in your app. I mean, yes, of course there are other ways--you *could* just make it a global variable.  It'd compile. Whether you *should* or not is another issue. ;)  But anyway--like I said before I'm sure there are other solutions, there usually are many solutions to any problem.  So hopefully someone will come along with another idea for you.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know much about cocos, but in Objective C you need to simply locate a reference to the object in question to access its properties.

There are several ways to access objects from other objects:

- Pass an instance of the object the properties of which you need to access to the initializer or another setter of the object that needs to perform the access
- Create a singleton instance and add a class method for accessing it
- Create a map (`NSDictionary`) or a cache (`NSCache`) that lets you locate instances of objects by a string key that your program assigns to them.